# Buscar por nome em planilha C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou tentando fazer uma busca por nome dentro de uma planilha Excel, por código funciona normal, mas gostaria de buscar por nome, quando faço a busca com o código abixo, retorna o erro:

> [image: erro que ocorre]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       _oleCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Nome FROM [Designa$] Where Nome=" + textBox1.Text;
       OleDbDataReader reader = _oleCmd.ExecuteReader();
       while (reader.Read())
       {
        textBox2.Text = reader.GetString(1);
       }
       reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,this.Text,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fora a falta de aspas você precisa "escapar" o valor passado pra query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esqueceu das aspas (`'`) na hora de procurar pela `string` do nome. Assim deve funcionar:

```
_oleCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Nome FROM [Designa$] Where Nome='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Ou

```
_oleCmd.CommandText = $"SELECT Nome FROM [Designa$] Where Nome='{textBox1.Text}'";
```

Comment: Ambos funcionaram!! Tive só que alterar o array pra 0.
Valeu, obrigado!!

Comment: Os dois são a mesma coisa escrita de maneiras diferentes. No segundo exemplo é usada a interpolação de strings, você pode ver mais sobre isso aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated